# What is the origin of the long version of the Gayatri mantra?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, gayatri-mantra

As far as I know the Gayatri mantra appears in Rig Veda 3.62.10:

> Om Bhur Buvaha Svaha
>
> Tat Savithur Varenyam
>
> Bhargo Devasya Dheemahi
>
> Dhiyo Yonaha Prachodayath

But in some books and on the Internet, I've also seen a longer version. For example, the longer version is found on [this](http://vishuji.org/sandhya_vandanam.htm) page as:

> Om Bhuh
>
> Om Bhuvaha
>
> Om Suvaha
>
> Om Mahaha
>
> Om Janaha
>
> Om Tapaha
>
> Om Satyam
>
> Om Tat Savithur Varenyam Bhargo Devasya Dheemahi Dhiyo Yonah
> Prachodayath
>
> Om apo jyotih raso amritam Brahma
>
> Bhur Bhuvas suvar
> Om

What is the origin of this longer version? Does it appear in the Rig Veda?

Comment: The longer version is used while doing Pranayama before starting a Puja or a Sandhyavandanam or for that matter any Vedic Ritual.

Comment: The longer version is aptly called as dheerga gayathri. It consists of pranavam, sapta vyahruthi and gayathri.

Answer (score 4):

The Origin of Long Version of Gayatri Mantra is from **Taitteriya Aranyaka of Yajurveda in 10.35.1**

> [[10-35-1]] 
>   ojo'si saho'si balamasi bhrÀjo'si devÀnÀÎ dhÀmanÀmÀ'si viÌvamasi 
>   viÌvÀyussarvamasi sarvÀyurabhibhÂroÎ gÀyatrÁmÀvÀhayÀmi savitrÁmÀvÀhayÀmi 
>   sarasvatÁmÀvÀhayÀmi chandarÍÁnÀvÀhayÀmi ÌriyamÀvÀhayÀmi gÀyatriyÀ 
>   gÀyatrÁcchando viÌvÀmitra ÃÍissavitÀ devatÀ'gnirmukhaÎ brahmÀ Ìiro 
>   viÍÉurhÃdayaÙrudraÌÌikhÀ pÃthivÁ yoniÏ prÀÉÀpÀnavyÀnodÀnasamÀnÀ saprÀÉÀ 
>   ÌvetavarÉÀ sÀÎkhyÀyanasagotrÀ gÀyatrÁ caturviÙÌatyakÍarÀ tripadÀ ÍaÊakukÍiÏ 
>   paÈcaÌÁrÍopanayane viniyogaÏ | 
>   **om bhu | 
>
>   om bhuvaÏ |
>
>   om suvaÏ | 
>
>   on mahaÏ | 
>
>   om janaÏ | 
>
>   om tapaÏ || 
>
>   om satyam | 
>
>   om tathsaviturvareÉyaÎ bhargo devasya dhÁmahi | 
>
>   dhiyo yo naÏ pracodayÀt | 
>
>   omÀpo jyotÁ raso'mÃtaÎ brahma bhÂrbhuvassuvarom |**

[image: Gayatri Long Form]

**One can see the long form of Gayatri above in the image above in 10-35-1**

Answer (score 3):

The longer version of the Gayatri Mantra mentioned in the question is found in the [Navagraha Sooktam](http://www.bharatiweb.com/English/Navagraha%20Sooktam%20Eng%20v1.pdf), the Vedic Hymn to the 9 planetary deities.

> Navagraha Sooktam v1
>
> 1 || navagrahasooktam || om shuklaambara dharam vishNum   shashi
>   varNam chatur bhujam |  prasanna  vadanam dhyaayet   sarva vighna
>   upashaantayay ||
>
> **om  bhoo: om  bhuva: om  suva: om  maha: om  jana:  om  tapa: om   satyam | om  tatsa vi turvareNyam  bhargo devasya   dheemahi |  dhiyo 
>   yona : prachodayaat | om  aapo jyoteeraso am rutam  brahma   bhoor
>   bhuva: suvarom ||**

Although I'm not quite sure where exactly this Sukta appears, in Rig Veda or in Atharva Veda.

I'm adding a second source.There is a procedure of doing Sandhyavandanam mentioned in the **Narada Purana**.The "long" Gayatri Mantra appears there among the Pranayama Mantras.

[image]

Comment: The following page lists "Navagraha Mantraha" as one of the Suktams being found in the Rig Veda.In my view Navagraha Suktam is just the same.http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/suktalst.html

Comment: The Rigeveda(RV) Taittiriya Samhita(TS) & Atharva Veda(AV) are the sources for the verses found in the Navagraha suktam.Checked from the collection that i have.To be specific-RV 1.35.2,TS 3.4.11.2a,RV 1.12.1,TS 2.5.8.5,RV  1.22.15,TS 1;5;5c, RV 4.57.1,AV 1.6.2,RV 1.164.41,AV 9.10.21 etc.

Comment: Where in Narada Purana it is mentioned.

Comment: @Ajay Just like the Devi Bhagavatam has the details of how to do Sandhyavandanam. the Narada Purana also has them. I am not sure though whether i can tell you where exactly in NP they are found. I will check the PDF from which the screenshot is taken.

Comment: I can search myself, I have Narada Purana

Comment: Ok so what you want me to do then? I will check the PDF if it mentions which chapter of NP they are found in. @Ajay So that it will be easy for you to search Or have you found them already?

Comment: You said you can't find till now. So I said I will search myself

Comment: @Ajay You can check [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/naradapurana6.html) page. Now it will be easy for u to  find where exactly in ur NP copy the procedures are contained.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/padmapurana14.html) is a complete mention of Gayatri Mantra in Padmapurana

**In Padmapurana Brahma detailed each relevant Deity in respect of each of the Twenty Four Letters of the Gayatri Mantra as follows: Agni, Vayu, Surya, Viyat (Akash),Yamaraja, Varun, Brihaspati, Parjanya, Indra, Gandharva, Pusha, Mitra, Twashta, Vasu, Marudganas, Soma, Angira, Vishwa Deva, Ashvini Kumars, Pragapati, Sampurna Devata, Rudra, Brahma and Shri Vishnu. The letter-to-letter seriatum of Deities represented in the Gayatri Mantra thus provided the ‘Vangmaya’/ ‘Vani Vishaya’ or the cross-referencing of the Letter-Deity implication. As regards the ‘Nyasa’ of the Aksharas of the Gayatri Mantra versus Body Limbs, the explanation is as follows: ‘Tat’-touch the thumbs of the feet; ‘Sa’-Gulpha (ankles); ‘Vi’-the two pindaliyas (calves); ‘thu’-ghutnas (Knees); ‘Var’-jangha (lap); ‘Re’-Terminal Part; ‘Nya’- ‘Andakosha; ‘M’-‘Kati bhagas’(  thighs); ‘Bha’-Nabhi Mandala; ‘orgo’-Udaram; ‘Dey’-both the breasts; ‘Va’- Hridaya; ‘Sya’-both the hands; ‘Dhee’-face; ‘Ma’-taalu; ‘hi’-top of Nasika( nose); ‘Dhi’-both the eyes; ‘Yo’- both bahus (hands); ‘Yo’- Lalaat; ‘Nah’-Muhka’s Purvabhaaga; ‘Pra’-‘Dakshna bhaag; ‘Cho’-Paschima bhaaga; ‘da’-Mukha’s Uttara Bhaga; ‘Yaat’-Mastak (head). By performing the Nyasa as above, all the ‘Aksharas’or the Letters are thus aligned to Brahma-Vishnu and Maheswara.**

*Another kind of Nyasa for the Sandhya-Kaalas is as follows:*

> Om Bhuriti Hridaye
>
> Om Bhuvah Shirasi
>
> Om Swaha Shikhayai Om
>
> Tatsaviuvarenyamithi Kalebarey
>
> Bhargo Devasya Dhimahi Netrayoh Om
>
> Dhiyoyonaha prachodayaatiti Karayoh
>
> Om Apo jyotee rasomritam Brahma
>
> Bhurbhuvah swarom

*The above Vyahruti and Twelve Omkaaraas along with Gayatri Mantra be performed at Sandhya Timings while touching water (Jala sparsha) followed by Pranayama Kriya thrice; then should follow the Gayatri Mantra Japa for as many times as possible. Then should follow ‘Punah-Nyasa’ or Repeat Nyasa as follows: Om Bhuh Padaabhyaam and touch the feet; Om Bhuvah Jaanubhyaam and touch both ‘ghutane’ (knees); Om Swahah Katyaam and touch kati bhaaga’ (thighs); Om Mahah Naabhou and touch Nabhistaan (navel); Om Janah Hridaye and touch Hridaya; Om Tapah Karaye and touch both the hands; Om Satyam and touch Lalaatey (Forehead) and finally recite the entire Mantra and touch the Shikha (tuft).*